Migrating spring from 4.x to 5.x and jdk 17
I have spring dependencies and also spring integration dependencies in my application.
I have migrated spring from 4.1.1.RELEASE to 5.3.39 and spring integration from 2.2.3.RELEASE to 5.5.20.
I have configuration for the rabbit mq like this.
<int-amqp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="testAmqpAdapter" channel="AppTestChnl"
        queue-names="${amqp.queue.test}" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        auto-startup="true" concurrent-consumers="${amqp.consumer.count}"
        channel-transacted="true" task-executor="taskExecutor"
        prefetch-count="2" tx-size="2" acknowledge-mode="AUTO"
        error-handler="messageErrorHandler" />

when I try to deploy the application I'm getting two error.

Unable find the attribute txSize


org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'txSize' of bean class [org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Bean property 'txSize' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?


Getting below error in the logs

14:03:07 [main] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory.connectHostPort 650]  - Attempting to connect to: ***:5672
14:03:08 [main] INFO  o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection 589] -Created new connection: connectionFactory#:0/SimpleConnection@1b1d9ff5 [delegate=amqp://***@***:5672/***, localPort= ***]
14:03:08 [AMQP Connection ***:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log 748]|HOSTNAME=***| - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'channelName' in vhost '***': received 'direct' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)
14:03:09 [AMQP Connection ***:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log 748]|HOSTNAME=***| - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'channelName' in vhost '***': received 'direct' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)
14:03:11 [AMQP Connection ***:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log 748]|HOSTNAME=***| - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'channelName' in vhost '***': received 'direct' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)
14:03:15 [AMQP Connection ***:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log 748]|HOSTNAME=***| - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'channelName' in vhost '***': received 'direct' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)
14:03:20 [AMQP Connection ***:5672] ERROR o.s.a.r.c.AbstractConnectionFactory$DefaultChannelCloseLogger.log 748]|HOSTNAME=***| - Shutdown Signal: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'type' for exchange 'channelName' in vhost '***': received 'direct' but current is 'fanout', class-id=40, method-id=10)

for the 1st issue i noticed that tx-size can be handled using prefetch-count="2" attribute.
If take that I don't see any error.

The change was made 5 years ago: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1032. Was replaced with batchSize from there. So, that is a bug in Spring Integration where we missed to remove that XML attribute according to upstream changes in Spring AMQP: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/9695.
The second one is an application bug. You have a channelName exchange declared as a direct, but it is as a fanout on RabbitMQ broker. If that is an intention, you simply can remove it from the broker and rerun your application.
